# CSS make label text align with select text

Tags: html, css

I am back-end dev who currently has to do front-end for a small task. My problem is this image

[image]

The background is just for debugging purposes. However this red line is to show that the text in the label (left) is not aligned with the text in the right. I am using React and here is my component which created both

```
<div className='select'>
  <label className='selectLabel'>{this.props.label}</label>
  <select id ='select' onChange={this.props.onChange}>
    {this.props.options}
  </select>
</div>
```

Here is my css so far as I have no idea what I am doing I just do random stuff and whatever works

```
.select{
   width:100%;
   padding-left: 2%;
   text-align: left;
   margin: 10px auto 10px;
   position: relative;
}
#select{
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 34px;
    width: 268px;
    background-color: aqua;
}
.selectLabel{
    clear: both;
    float:left;
    display:block;
    height: 34px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 268px;
    line-height:25px;
    background-color: aquamarine;
}
```

What should I add or change in order to make both texts align with each other?

Comment: The problem is not related to React at all, but rather to HTML and CSS. For easier debugging please consider extracting and saving the generated HTML. You can get it using your browser's developer tools. My first guess would be the floating.

Comment: Set `line-height: 34px` to `.selectLabel`.

Comment: `.selectLabel {display: inline-block}` should be enough, also you don't need `float`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `display: flex;
align-items: center;` to `.selectLabel` will solve the issue

```css
.select{
   width:100%;
   padding-left: 2%;
   text-align: left;
   margin: 10px auto 10px;
   position: relative;
}
#select{
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 34px;
    width: 268px;
    background-color: aqua;
}
.selectLabel{
    clear: both;
    float:left;
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 34px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 268px;
    line-height:25px;
    background-color: aquamarine;
}
```

```html
<div class='select'>
  <label class='selectLabel'>{this.props.label}</label>
  <select id ='select'>
    <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Global browser support without prefixing: 86.91% (http://caniuse.com/#search=flex)

Comment: Also compared to the other solutions this one introduces a lot of layout complexity that will backfire later on.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to float the label or define its height. Use inline-block as the display mode for it.

```
.selectLabel{
    display:inline-block;
    background-color: aquamarine;
}
```

See code pen for a working example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qXaoGb

Answer (score 1):

Use `line-height` instead of `vertical-align: middle;`

and `inline-block` instead of `display:block; float:left;`

for your label.

https://jsfiddle.net/r8bzo8c1/1/

```css
.select{
   width:100%;
   padding-left: 2%;
   text-align: left;
   margin: 10px auto 10px;
   position: relative;
}
#select{
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 34px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: aqua;
}
.selectLabel{
    display:inline-block;
    height: 34px;
    width: 150px;
    line-height:34px;
    background-color: aquamarine;
}
```

```html
<div className='select'>
  <label class='selectLabel'>Label</label><select id ='select'>
     <option>A</option>
     <option>B</option>
  </select>
</div>
```